# Can't Remove Padding From Bottom of Form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, padding

Can someone tell me how can I remove the bottom padding from a form with no padding?

The form padding property is set to:

```
this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
FormBorderStyle=sizable
```

but the form has a bottom padding...

I can do a new one, but I prefer to understand the behavior of that form.

[image]

http://heldervaldez.com/WinForm.png

and Code FormMainDesigner.cs:

```
// FormMain
 // 
 this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
 this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
 this.AutoSize = true;
 this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnablePreventFocusChange;
 this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
 this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
 this.CausesValidation = false;
 this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1278, 758);
 this.ControlBox = false;
 this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
 this.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
 this.Controls.Add(this.labelEmail);
 this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
 this.Controls.Add(this.radDock1);
 this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
 this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
 this.HelpButton = true;
 this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
 this.IsMdiContainer = true;
 this.MainMenuStrip = this.menuStrip1;
 this.Name = "FormMain";
 this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
 this.Text = "Sistema de Monitorização Energética";
 this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
 this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormMain_Load);
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.citiesBindingSource)).EndInit();
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSetGeografia)).EndInit();
 this.menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
 this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
 this.contextMenuStripRoot.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.contextMenuStripTensionTypes.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.contextMenuStripCUnit.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.radDock1)).EndInit();
 this.radDock1.ResumeLayout(false);
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.toolTabStrip1)).EndInit();
 this.toolTabStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.documentContainer1)).EndInit();
 ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.toolTabStrip2)).EndInit();
 this.toolTabStrip2.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.ResumeLayout(false);
 this.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: Please tag as `.net` or whatever you are using, and post the code. Otherwise no one can "understand the behavior of that form". Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank You Smandoli. Maybe it is an inheritance problem, but I can't find the cause...

Comment: Isn't that the StatusStrip on the bottom?

Comment: No LarsTech, It Isn't the StatusStrip. I will publish a link to a new screeshot with statusStrip.

Comment: Why isn't the StatusStrip visible in the first image?  You have the IsMdiContainer = true, but it doesn't look like there is room for a client form.  It's unclear what that white border is.

Comment: Lars Tech, Thank you for editing my question. In the first image I removed statusStrip to outwit that possibility. I will post a complete image. I've marked the problem with a red rectangle.

Comment: Maybe something with that RadDock control.  Is it Dock=Filled?  Can't see it from your code example.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict between these lines:
Remove either

```
this.AutoSize = true;
```

or

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1278, 758);
```

According to MSDN AutoSize is meant to guarantee that all controls fit on the page without scrolling. Making the form even larger afterwards is probably OK by it.. hence the extra room before the statusbar, which presumably is docked to the bottom as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was an invisible label in the bottom of Form. Just had to delete the label. 
The following image shows the label.
http://heldervaldez.com/label.png
Thank you for trying to help.